# Deserializing an object with protobuf-net with derived type for some field

Tags: c#, serialization, deserialization, protobuf-net

There is some logic that stores data of type `DataContainer<BaseClass>` using protobuf-net to some repository. Lets say I need to create new DerivedClass, so all new instances of `DataContainer<DerivedClass>` would be serialized properly, but for purposes of back-compatibility I want to have option to deserialize some previously saved data as DerivedClass without changing any data in repository.

```
class Program
{
    
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var baseObject = new BaseClass()
        {
            Name = "some name"
        };
        
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            ProtoBuf.Serializer.Serialize(stream, new DataContainer<BaseClass>{ Data = baseObject, DataBase64 = "base class Base64"});
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            //System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'BaseClass' to type 'DerivedClass'.'
            var result = ProtoBuf.Serializer.Deserialize<DataContainer<DerivedClass>>(stream);
        }
    }
}


public interface IDataInterface
{

}

[ProtoBuf.ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(1001, typeof(DerivedClass))]
public class BaseClass: IDataInterface
{
    [ProtoBuf.ProtoMember(1)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[ProtoBuf.ProtoContract]
public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    [ProtoBuf.ProtoMember(1)]
    public int Index { get; set; }
}

public interface IContainerInterface
{
    IDataInterface Content { get; }
}

[ProtoContract]
public class DataContainer<T> : IContainerInterface where T: IDataInterface
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public T Data { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public string DataBase64 { get; set; }
    
    public IDataInterface Content => this.Data;
}
```

Is there any way to deserialize `DataContainer<DerivedClass>` out of serialized `DataContainer<BaseClass>`? The other way is to use some higher-level converter after deserializing `DataContainer<BaseClass>` that would simply turn it to `DataContainer<DerivedClass>`, but it involves some property-coping, which I would like to avoid as much as possible

Comment: It might be useful to separate your data-model from your serialization classes. That can allow for a bit more flexibility when changing the data model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the item you're serializing *was a `DerivedClass`, then I would *expect* this to already work. However, if you need to deserialize existing data that only knew about `BaseClass`, then you would need to deserialize a `DataContainer<BaseClass>` and then test to find that `Data` *is* actually a `DerivedClass`.

Comment: Thanks for quick answer. Yeah, at the moment all data is stored as `BaseClass`, but with time data types will become mixed in repository. I hoped to write some custom deserializer that would create instance of DerivedClass at some point, something that Serializer.Merge<T>(..) would do. Not exactly, but similar in a way

Comment: @Pallaris that's not how inheritance and generics usually work together, though...